# Searching a function in Matlab that fits to python function "ndimage.map_coordinates"

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation, spline, code-translation

I'm trying convert some code from python to matlab. It worked so far... until I came to this python function:

```
ndimage.map_coordinates(inputarray, [x,y], output=output)
```

I'm searching for a corresponding function in matlab... but I don't understand the python function, so it is difficult for me to find the right one in matlab.
I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: Hello Mr E, thanks for your answer. Yes I do already trying to understand the documentation. And I already checked the code of map_coordinates and thought about converting this function line by line... but I would prefer a shorter solution.

Comment: ... I think the matlap function interp2 is more or less what i'm searching for

Comment: If I make in Matlab:

X = (0:11);
X = reshape(t,3,4)';
Xq=[0.5, 2];
Yq=[0.5, 1];
Vq = interp2(X,Xq,Yq,'spline');

I get as result -2 1


... why is the result in Numpy-function map_coordinates for the same Array and input-values a different. (See the result in the example of the map_coordination documentation)
What is the difference between these two functions? Has anybody a idea or can anybody explain me?